# how to create same fragment with different arguments in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to create same fragment multiple times in view pager with different arguments how can i do it?

Now i have a static single argument constructor in a fragment which i call to initialize the fragment

Is there a simple way to do this.

Comment: What you are doing is right. Its the simplest way.  You are using a static getInstance method and passing arguments inside it right.

Comment: thanks for your comment @RageshRamesh

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setArguments()` method, for each of your Fragment. Do something like this:

```
Fragment myFragment = new Fragment();
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("data_1","Hello");
myFragment.setArguments(data);
```

Then in your Fragment, do this:

```
Bundle data = getArguments();
String data_1 = data.getString("data_1");
```